# Should I check for invalid inputs in a programming quiz?

Tags: input

I will attend an online quiz that requires me to write a function making some hysteresis calculations.

In the question, the input range, the number of output levels and the thresholds for the noise levels were given. But I'm not sure whether should I add conditions to prevent users from entering an input exceeding the given input levels. The question says that the input will be a percentage, so I'm not sure if we can think that we should not worry about the inputs bigger than 100 or not.

I just added some calculations based on the preset threshold values given in the question, but I can also make the threshold calculations generic on the input and the output range. Is it necessary? Should I ask the advertiser to clarify it or is there a defacto standard for programming quizzes that we can accept?

Comment: Generally for quizzes and contests you are allowed to assume that the input meets the specifications stated in the question, and are not required to correctly handle invalid input.  The problem here is that the specification is possibly ambiguous: does "percentage" include things like `250%`?  If you can't tell from context what the intent was, then you can either ask for clarification, or handle it in whatever way you choose and hope you are right.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is graph given for input and outputs and the the axis given for the input percentage shows 100 at the end of the axis. Usually they run the function in a tester and see the speed and the memory usage so I did not want to bother with checking this. If only a human will read my answer, I think it will not be a problem but otherwise it will decrease the performance of course.